# Find a set of common elements from a multi-dimensional array recursively

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array, combinations

I have a multi-dimensional array:

```
a=[[2,3,4],[1,3,4],[1,2],[1,2,3,4]]
```

i've to compare all the 4 sub-arrays and get common elements.Next,take 3 subarrays at a time and get common elements.then take 2 sub arrays at a time and get common elements, in RUBY.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the job in recent Ruby versions:

```
a.length.downto(1).map{|i| a.combination(i).map{|sub| sub.inject(&:&)}}
#=> [[[]], [[], [3, 4], [2], [1]], [[3, 4], [2], [2, 3, 4], [1], [1, 3, 4], [1, 2]], [[2, 3, 4], [1, 3, 4], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4]]]
```

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518507/is-this-the-best-way-to-grab-common-elements-from-a-hash-of-arrays/2518549#2518549) a related question with similar solution. The "trick" is in method `Array#&`, which calculates the intersection (as a set operation) of the two arrays. It is [associative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associativity) operation, so we can apply it on each subarray in turn, keeping the accumulated result, hence `inject` is perfect for it. In short, `array.inject(&:&)` will result with a greatest common subset of elements in every member of `array`. `&:&` is just a Ruby shorthand for making a `Proc` out of method named `&` and submitting it as a block to `inject`, instead of writing:

```
array.inject{|a,e| a & e}
```

Comment: @Mladen, Jablonović, this is an awesomely elegant solution. Can you update your answer a bit to explain a little more on how this works. Specifically, what is `&:&` and how does it work with `Enumerable#inject`?